# Laravel (eloquent) accessors: Calculate only once

Tags: php, laravel, optimization, eloquent, accessor

I have a Laravel model which have a calculated accessor:

Model *Job* has some *JobApplications* which are associated to a *User*.
I want to get whether the user has already applied for a job or not.

For that I created an accessor `user_applied` which gets the `applications` relationships with the current user. This works okay, but the accessor is being calculated (making query) every time I access to the field.

Is there any *easy* way to calculate the accessor only **once**

```
/**
 * Whether the user applied for this job or not.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getUserAppliedAttribute()
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->applications()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->exists();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d instead create a method on your `User` model that you pass a `Job` to, and returns a boolean as to whether the user’s applied or not:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function jobApplications()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(JobApplication::class);
    }

    public function hasAppliedFor(Job $job)
    {
        return $this->jobApplications->contains('job_id', $job->getKey());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```php
$applied = User::hasAppliedFor($job);
```

Comment: Cheers. this cool turnaround will surely work for this problem. But it'd be great if there was a way to calculate accessors only once...

Comment: You can set a property on the model. Then on subsequent calls, check if the property has a value and if so use it or if not, perform the calculation.

Comment: yes, that would do the trick... quite tricky but would work. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in a comment and really not tricky at all

```
 protected $userApplied=false;
/**
 * Whether the user applied for this job or not.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
 public function getUserAppliedAttribute()
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return false;
    }

    if($this->userApplied){
        return $this->userApplied;
    }else{
        $this->userApplied = $this->applications()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->exists();

        return $this->userApplied;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can set `user_applied` value to the `model->attributes` array and return it from attributes array on the next access.

```
public function getUserAppliedAttribute()
{
    $user_applied =  array_get($this->attributes, 'user_applied') ?: !Auth::check() && $this->applications()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->exists();
    array_set($this->attributes, 'user_applied', $user_applied);
    return $user_applied;
}
```

The `array_get` will return `null` when accessed first time, which will cause the next side of `?:` to be executed. The `array_set` will set the evaluated value to the `'user_applied'` key. In the subsequent calls, `array_get` will return previously set value.

The **bonus advantage** with this approach is that if you've set `user_applied` somewhere in your code (eg `Auth::user()->user_applied = true`), it will reflect that, meaning it will return that value without doing any additional thing.